# Text showing different colours in IE/Firefox Mobile & Firefox Desktop(!)

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I'm really struggling with this one!

In IE and on my mobile phone (Firefox browser) the text in the top left of my website is showing in the correct color: #e2e2e2, but in Firefox for my desktop, it's showing in #2e2e2e

I can't figure out how I managed to do it, and I don't know what sections of my code to post lol.

scottdaviesdesign.co.uk is the URL. If anyone can figure it out from the source code, that would be awesome.

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: use the dev tools to find where it comes from. each style shows from which file it is and which line.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, wjay do you mean dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason #light-table in my CSS was causing the issue.